# Firebase dynamic link leaves behind a blank page in Safari on iOS 14

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

We have configured and tested dynamic deep deferred links leveraging firebase for our web to app transition experience.

We have a web site where the user can choose to take an action that requires use of our native iOS app; we dynamically create the link and then navigate to it. This successfully either opens our app or the app store (we choose to bypass the preview page, but the problem I am describing occurs either way).

The problem is that the links page (e.g. https://links.example.com/do_something) is a blank page in Safari. If the user uses the iOS "back" navigation that appears in the top left corner of the app, or if the user manually switches back to Safari, this new blank page is now the front page in Safari instead of the web application that was open when the user clicked our link. We can launch the link with a target _blank so that at least our page also stays open, but the blank link page is still at the front. This is confusing for users who want to get back to the web page.

Here is what the page looks like:

[image]

Is there a trick we can use so that the blank page is never shown, or at least closes immediately when the app is launched? We tried opening it in an iframe but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the social tags option while creating the short-link ?

[image: ShortLink]

This will create a page preview on safari.